# Why won't QToolTips appear on QActions within a QMenu

Tags: python, tooltip, pyside, qmenu, qaction

I'm doing an app with in GUI written with `PySide`. I set a `QMenu` on a `QPushButton`, added several `QActions` via `QMenu.addAction`. To further explain these actions to the user I added `QToolTip`'s to these with `QAction.setToolTip`.

When I run the GUI now my `QToolTip` won't show. The example posted below reproduces the same issue, any ideas?

Thanks in advance

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui

class Example(QtGui.QPushButton):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setText('TestMenu')
        self.setToolTip('This is a Test Button')

        menu = QtGui.QMenu(self)
        action_1 = menu.addAction('Action1')
        action_1.setToolTip('This is action 1')
        action_2 = menu.addAction('Action2')
        action_2.setToolTip('This is action 2')
        action_3 = menu.addAction('Action3')
        action_3.setToolTip('This is action 3')
        action_4 = menu.addAction('Action4')
        action_4.setToolTip('This is action 4')

        self.setMenu(menu)
        self.show()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()

    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In Qt-5.1 or later, you can simply use [QMenu.setToolTipsVisible](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#toolTipsVisible-prop), and the menu items will show their tooltips as expected (see [QTBUG-13663](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-13663)):

```
    menu.setToolTipsVisible(True)
```

However, for Qt-4.* and Qt-5.0, the situation is different. If an action is added to a toolbar, its tooltip **will** be shown; but if the same action is added to a `QMenu`, it won't be, and there is no built-in API to change that. There are a couple of ways to work around this. One is to use [status tips](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaction.html#statusTip-prop) instead, which will show the menu-item information in the status-bar. The other is to implement the menu-item tooltip functionality yourself using the [QMenu.hovered](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaction.html#statusTip-prop) signal and [QToolTip.showText](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtooltip.html#showText):

```
        self.menu = QtGui.QMenu(self)
        ...
        self.menu.hovered.connect(self.handleMenuHovered)

    def handleMenuHovered(self, action):
        QtGui.QToolTip.showText(
            QtGui.QCursor.pos(), action.toolTip(),
            self.menu, self.menu.actionGeometry(action))
```

Comment: Thanks, probably not the answer I was looking for ;) - but it surely helped me getting on the way!! I'll post my solution below

Comment: The next answer down (using setToolTipsVisible on the QMenu) is actually the correct answer for Qt 5.1+.

Comment: @Wingware. The original question was about pyside, and hence qt4 only. However, I've now updated my answer to cover both qt4 and qt5.

Comment: setToolTipsVisible does not appear to help on the Mac. Perhaps the Mac native menus don't support that?

Answer (score 9):

Actually you don't have to do any workaround to display your tooltip, since Qt 5.1, you can use QMenu's property [`toolTipsVisible`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#toolTipsVisible-prop), which is by default set to `false`.

See the [related Qt suggestion](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-13663).

Comment: This really works and should be the accepted solution, you will have to make sure that this property is checked for every menu and sub menu that have in your application or the tooltips won't be shown for those menus

Answer (score 2):

With ekhumoro helping me on the way got to this solution. It's probably not the most beautiful thing, and the code below positions the menu and the tool tips somewhat arkward, but in my actual programm it looks quite neat.

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QPushButton):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setText('TestMenu')
        self.setToolTip('This is a Test Button')

        menu = QtGui.QMenu(self)
        action_1 = menu.addAction('Action1')
        action_1.setToolTip('This is action 1')
        action_2 = menu.addAction('Action2')
        action_2.setToolTip('This is action 2')
        action_3 = menu.addAction('Action3')
        action_3.setToolTip('This is action 3')
        action_4 = menu.addAction('Action4')
        action_4.setToolTip('This is action 4')

        action_1.hovered.connect(lambda pos = [self], parent = action_1, index = 0: show_toolTip(pos, parent, index))
        action_2.hovered.connect(lambda pos = [self], parent = action_2, index = 1: show_toolTip(pos, parent, index))
        action_3.hovered.connect(lambda pos = [self], parent = action_3, index = 2: show_toolTip(pos, parent, index))
        action_4.hovered.connect(lambda pos = [self], parent = action_4, index = 3: show_toolTip(pos, parent, index))

        self.setMenu(menu)
        self.show()

def show_toolTip(pos, parent, index):
    '''
    **Parameters**
        pos:    list
            list of all parent widget up to the upmost

        parent: PySide.QtGui.QAction
            the parent QAction

        index:  int
            place within the QMenu, beginning with zero
    '''
    position_x = 0
    position_y = 0
    for widget in pos:
        position_x += widget.pos().x()
        position_y += widget.pos().y()

    point = QtCore.QPoint()
    point.setX(position_x)
    point.setY(position_y + index * 22) # set y Position of QToolTip

    QtGui.QToolTip.showText(point, parent.toolTip())

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()

    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have to say I'm not perfectly happy with this, mainly because the `show_toolTip` function has to be global, for the lambda operator didn't recognize it when I had it in the class (`self.show_toolTip`). I'm still open for suggesetions if someone has a suggestion.

Comment: Not sure if you're still interested, but I've added a simpler solution to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of showing tooltip immediately one can just update the tooltip of the parent (menu) when hovering and wait for the tooltip to be shown! Therefore:

```
    menu = QtGui.QMenu(self)
    action_1 = menu.addAction('Action1')
    action_1.setToolTip('This is action 1')
    ...
    menu.hovered.connect(self.handleMenuHovered)

def handleMenuHovered(self, action):
    action.parent().setToolTip(action.toolTip())
```